Spy movie\thriller with stakeout van and laser beam?
I'm looking for the title of a movie I've seen in the 80s or early 90s. But all I remember of it are the following sequences:

There was some sort of laser beam or beacon at night.
A man and a colleague are investigating something.
They are at the man's house where there is also his wife and child.
There was a van in the movie.
The man and some colleague were on a stakeout in the van.
The man gets killed by some bad guys.
I'm not sure but I think the bad guys get into the man's house and he manages to hide his wife and child somewhere in the house.
Later on, the wife and the child are seen on a lawn in a park.
The wife plays some audio tape, expecting music on it, but then there is some recording made by the late husband.

That's about it. Those are the only fragments I remember. I've googled for all the keywords mentioned above but wasn't able to figure out the movie's title. I assume it was a US movie.

@mikehussey: It's not a Bond movie. Don't remember a mother and child being in any of them.

@Anton: I checked the trailer and it's unfortunately not Patriot Games either.

Was it a big budget movie? Also would you class it as conspiracy or action?

@Workin'classhero: From the few fragments I remember, I'd say it was a conspiracy movie -- not sure though. Can't say whether it was a big budget movie or not.

Sounds like there are elements from The Terminator and Terminator 2.

I know that's much more recent, but.. could be "The Betrayed"? Some element remember "A Perfect Murder", too.

@AlasdairCM: I believe the movie predates Terminator. I've seen all of the Terminator movies and it's none of them.

@VoT: It's definitely not "A Perfect Murder". It's not "The Betrayed" either. But nice guess. Just watched the trailer and there were quite some elements there. Thanks anyway!

Sounds somewhat familiar to me, but I can't tell just yet. Do you have any idea of what famous actors there were in it perhaps? And does it involve kidnapping?

@poepje: Unfortunately, I can't remember who the actors were. Hm, don't remember a kidnapping in the fragments I recall... but there might have been one in the movie.

Was it Jennifer 8? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_8

@user4125: I don't remember the wine glass scence. But since you recall the exact same things, it could very well be the same movie we are looking for. :-)

The movie you are looking for is The Last Song (1980). I looked for this movie for years and then found it a few years ago. They use the laser from the van to record the conversation inside the room.  But the laser is revealed by a glass of wine. The two men who record the conversation are murdered, but not before one of them hides the undecoded tape in with his wife's tapes.
EDIT:
I didn't read the additional comments until after I posted this answer. I see that someone else mentioned the glass of wine.
The conspiracy is that a company has contaminated an area with a toxic chemical. To hide this fact, they are planning on blowing up a tanker truck loaded with the same chemical while it is passing through the same area. Then the chemical's presence will be blamed on the truck being blown up and only on the truck being blown up.
A bad guy is looking for the husband's tape. He breaks in and attacks the wife. She gets away but doesn't know what the guy was after.

Thank you very much! That was exactly the movie I was looking for! Wonderful.

All these scenes take place in the movie ERASER.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116213/?ref_=nv_sr_2
